# Upstart does not work

Tags: upstart, node.js

I followed this tutorial to set up upstart for my node.js server:
http://howtonode.org/deploying-node-upstart-monit

The problem is, that when I try to run "start mynodeprogram", I get the floowing error:

```
root@v:/# start mynodeprogram
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

I installed upstart with the following command:

```
root@v:~# apt-get install upstart
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  upstart
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/272 kB of archives.
After this operation, 717 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously deselected package upstart.
(Reading database ... 43793 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking upstart (from .../upstart_0.6.6-1_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up upstart (0.6.6-1) ...
```

Hope you can help me...

Comment: Did you try to reboot? Yes, I know this is not a qualified answer, but I got this message when I had trouble with a machine such that I had to reboot. Don't know whether it was the cause or a symptom.

Comment: I'll try it out!

Comment: Meinersbur is my hero! xD Upstart now works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try to reboot?  A lot of times that can fix it right away.

Comment: Seems many of my Upstart woes have been solved by rebooting the machine.

Comment: One time where "did you try turning it off and on again" *actually* is helpful :D